# Flutter Bloc change state from different widget

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

On my apps home page, I have a list view that rebuilds whenever the user clicks on a new page.
I have implemented the block pattern using the flutter_bloc plugin but I don't know how to change the state from another widget.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two things you will have to keep in mind for changing state with flutter bloc:

- Dependency injection (DI) of a bloc.
- Interaction with your bloc instance.

### Dependency injection of a bloc

*Case 1. You need to provide bloc to widget subtree within one route.*

---

To provide a single instance of a bloc to multiple widgets within a subtree you use `BlocProvider` widget. It creates bloc instance, automatically disposes of it when needed and provides bloc to its children via `BlocProvider.of<T>(context)`, where `T` is the name of your bloc:

```dart
BlocProvider(
  create: (BuildContext context) => BlocA(),
  child: ChildA(),
);
```

Keep in mind, that by deafult it is created with property `lazy: true`, means that `create: (BuildContext context) => BlocA(),` will be executed after invoke of `BlocProvider.of<T>(context)`. If you dont want it - set `lazy: false` in advance.

*Case 2. You need to provide bloc to widgets from another route (to another context).*

---

`BlocProvider` automatically disposes of a bloc instance with context of new route instantiated, but that will not happen if you use `BlocProvider.value`:

```dart
BlocProvider.value(
  value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),
  child: ScreenA(),
);
```

Important note: *`BlocProvider.value` should only be used for providing existing instances to new subtree, do not create Bloc instance with it*

### Interaction with your bloc instance

Starting from `bloc v6.1.0` `context.bloc` and `context.repository` are deprecated in favor of `context.read` and `context.watch`.

`context.select` allows to update UI based on a part of a bloc state:

```dart
    final name = context.select((UserBloc bloc) => bloc.state.user.name);
```

`context.read` access a bloc with a BuildContext and do not result rebuilds.
`context.watch` gets a value from the nearest ancestor provider of its type and subscribes to the provider.

**To access the bloc's state**

If you need a widget rebuilding due bloc value changing use `context.watch` or `BlocBuilder`:

```dart
// Using context.watch at the root of the build method will result in the entire widget being rebuilt when the bloc state changes. 
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final state = context.watch<MyBloc>().state;
  return Text('$state');
}
```

or with `BlocBuilder`:

```dart
// If the entire widget does not need to be rebuilt, either use BlocBuilder to wrap the parts that should rebuild
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyState>(
    builder: (context, state) => Text('$state'),
  );
}
```

**To access the bloc so that an event can be added**

Use context.read:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => context.read<MyBloc>().add(MyEvent()),
    ...
  )
}
```

Comment: This should be in their very first tutorial. **BlocProvider automatically disposes of a bloc instance with context of new route instantiated, but that will not happen if you use BlocProvider.value:** I've lost countless hours trying to figure out how to prevent the auto disposal. I use a setup where the blocs are created in standalone services and used by multiple widgets. It was such a pain to deal with the auto-disposal. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Could you also share a recommendation in what cases I should youse BlocBuilder or context.watch to trigger the UI rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `BlocProvider` to a common ansestor like as a parent of your `MaterialApp` widget, or you can pass the bloc to your new page like this:

```
BlocProvider.value(
  value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),
  child: ScreenB(),
);
```