# Different instances of the same cubit (local scope)in the same tree

Tags: flutter

Is it bad practice to create multiple instances of the same bloc/cubits in the tree?  I'm creating an instance of the cubit and using it in a few locations in the tree-like so.

```
BlocBuilder<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  cubit: blocA, // provide the local cubit instance
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on BlocA's state
  }
)
```

... but the blocs are scoped to a single widget with this method. I'm using this technique 3 times in the widget tree (splitting up my widgets into different classes). My console is spitting out several instances of the bloc in question from the `BlocObserver`. The blocs "work" but I'm suspicious I'm going about things the incorrect way...

Comment: Do you create bloc instance inside `BlocBuilder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you misunderstood the core concept of providing a bloc instance to your widget tree. You need `BlocBuilder` to set up the `BuildContext` for your widgets, that depend on bloc, and to minimize the scope of widgets, that will be marked for rebuild on bloc changes.
Yes this is very bad practice to have multiple bloc instances as it will almost nullify its usefulness to your app. To provide a single instance to your widgets use `BlocProvider` or `BlocProvider.value`, more about it you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66725440/13701546) or [here](http://bloclibrary.dev)